# no recording happens using bluez-alsa and sco profile

Tags: bluetooth, alsa, bluez

I am trying to record from Bluetooth headset. I have included bluez-alsa package along with my other yocto packages and compiled.

when I try to arecord, the recording is not happening and a sound or noise comes out of the headset. I am using bluealsa with sco profile.

The bluez-alsa service is running and the headset is connected. Even the playback is also not happening with SCO profile. But when I try with a2dp profile playback is happening.

```
aplay -D bluealsa:HCI=hci0,DEV=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx,PROFILE=a2dp sound.wav
```

is working

```
arecord -f S16_LE -D bluealsa:HCI=hci0,DEV=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx,PROFILE=sco test2.wav
```

is not working, random noise is coming out

```
aplay -D bluealsa:HCI=hci0,DEV=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx,PROFILE=sco sound.wav
```

is not working, random noise is coming out